# Xamarin Android bindings library for Jitsi

Tags: android, xamarin, jitsi

I'm trying to create in Xamarin Android the Jitsi Bindings Library. I've got all the dependecies aar (66 items) by following this guide:

https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/dev-guide/dev-guide-android-sdk

(Maven repository https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/raw/master/releases)

And this is the result so far: it is missing `JitsiMeetActivity`

[image]

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Do you have a repository where I can take a look at the metadata.xml?

Comment: @tequilaslammer, hi, if you intend the metadata.xml file in the transform folder of the project, it is untouched. Thanks

Comment: I started to create a binding with the latest version 2.9.0 and noticed that there is more than only the JitsiMeetActivity missing. Not explainable to me is that the api.xml.class-parse contains the missing pieces while api.xml and api.xml.fixed not.

Comment: Yes, for me too, many classes are missing

Answer (score 1):

to generate the JitsiMeetActivity class, add the 'XamarinLibrary.Xamarin.Android.Facebook.React.ReactNative' nuget to the binding project and rebuild it.

Comment: I add it. But it still error:
 Error CS0738: 'JitsiMeetActivity' does not implement interface member 'IPermissionAwareActivity.CheckPermission(string, int, int)'. 'ContextWrapper.CheckPermission(string?, int, int)' cannot implement 'IPermissionAwareActivity.CheckPermission(string, int, int)' because it does not have the matching return type of 'int'. (CS0738) (JitsiAndroidBinding)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue..

It seems that the binding process misses all the classes that extend from a base class...

as an example try also looking for the `JitsiMeetActivityInterface` interface definition, its a really simple class but its also missing from the binding process as well as a few others.

Happy to work with you on this too if you like.

Comment: Hi, it would be nice

Comment: How you fix it?